# Need help minimizing the loss of time for data collection

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, parallel-processing, process

I am trying to come up with the best way to minimize the loss of time in a data harvesting application I am building. Here are some of the restraints/factors:

- I can only query for data every 12 seconds on a specific channel
- I can connect to as many channels simultaneously.
- I want to keep the number of channels in use to a minimum

With these factors in mind, I have thought of a solution, but would like for more input.

I have decided to in a way load balance this collection of data. My thoughts are this:

- Main Program utilizes m processes (for now I am thinking 4).
- Each process uses n threads, where each thread is listening on a channel.(for now I am thinking 12).
- There is a variable `thread_start_time_factor = 12 seconds / n threads`
- There is a variable `process_start_time_factor = thread_start_time_factor / m processes`
- Each thread query's data every 12 seconds, however threads start consecutively after one another based on the `thread_start_time_factor`. So if I am using 12 threads, thread 1 starts, (1 second pause), thread 2 starts, ... This way data collection is now happening every 1 second.
- Each process then starts one after the other based on the
  `process_start_time_factor`

In theory, data collection **SHOULD** be happening every `process_start_time_factor` If going with the configuration above, the `process_start_time_factor` should be .250 seconds. (If my logic is wrong here, please let me know).

Now here is my question. Is this a *good* way to do this? My thoughts for using multiple processes is to essentially capture data whenever the other processes are not. The program will be written in Python (Not that it matters). Has anyone had experience with (weird) data collection restrictions like this where they have to think outside the box? Thanks to all of those who reply in advance. I am for sure open to other solutions.

Comment: might be better if you could actually write some real code to do this and submit it to codereview.stackexchange.com.  that said, why are you using so many processes/threads?  why not just use two and alternate between them before the time runs out.  also what is a "channel", why do you need to switch?

Comment: @SamMason I don't want to begin writing any code until I have a good idea about this. I am harvesting data on a certain site, and I can make a request every 12 seconds with out getting rate limited. So, each channel is essentially a web session that is running on a proxy.

Comment: why not have a chat with the admin of the site?  these days it's generally considered bad form or even illegal to have code hammering a site without their permission

Comment: @SamMason I have already read their ToS and it complies with what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given that you're using proxies, not linked to the site, and are being somewhat obscure about the question, suggests it's bordering on illegal

that said, some numbers you've not given are how long each request takes (e.g. TTFB, total duration, total data transferred) and what it takes to process the responses.

assuming you're not doing much processing on ingress, then I'd just go with an `asyncio` (i.e. no process/thread parallelism) approach as it's much easier to get the coordination straight.  multithreading/process coordination is much awkward to reason about

you should be able to saturate a 1GB connection with HTTP requests from a single thread, maybe just using multiple processes to do post-processing so that doesn't get in the way